# Eilenberg–Maclane space: nonvanishing cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

I would like to prove (self study) that $H^{np}(K(\mathbb{Z},n),\mathbb{Z})\neq 0$, where $n$ is even , $p\geq1$ and $K(\mathbb{Z},n)$ is the [Eilenberg–Maclane space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space).

I used the adjunction between $[ *,K(G,n)]$ and $H^{n}(*,G)$ and I found that it suffices to prove that $[K(\mathbb{Z},n),K(\mathbb{Z},np)]\neq 0$ but I can't continue the proof. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you find this problem in a book? The only thing I can think of is to try to do it by induction: note that it's true for $n=2$ ($\mathbb{CP}^\infty$ has nonvanishing cohomology in every even degree) and then try to work out something with the Leray–Serre spectral sequence for the loop space fibration, but that doesn't seem to be very tractable... There are classical results about the rational cohomology ring of $K(\mathbb{Z}, n)$ that directly imply this result, but it's probably harder to prove...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me write $B^n A$ for $K(A, n)$. The Yoneda lemma implies that $[B^n \mathbb{Z}, B^{np} \mathbb{Z}]$ is precisely the set of natural transformations $H^n(-, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^{np}(-, \mathbb{Z})$. An obvious candidate for such a natural transformation is the $p^{th}$ cup power

$$H^n(-, \mathbb{Z}) \ni \alpha \mapsto \alpha^p \in H^{np}(-, \mathbb{Z})$$

and to show that this is nonzero it suffices to find a single space on which it is nonzero, for which you can pick $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$.

Comment: Something that I hadn't realized before (but in retrospect obvious from the proof that $[B^n\pi, B^m\pi']$ is the set of cohomology operations) is that cohomology operations are not natural transformations between the $H^i$ as functors to groups, but rather as functors to sets; so the fact that $\alpha^p$ is not a homomorphism doesn't matter.

Comment: Haha, very nice! Much simpler than what I had in mind :)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't understand where you used the fact that n is even. How do we know that for $\mathbb{C}P^{\infinity}$ is not zero?

Comment: @user210251: You can compute the cohomology ring of $\Bbb{CP}^\infty$ to be $\Bbb Z[c_1]$, where $|c_1| = 2$. So $\Bbb{CP}^\infty$ has cohomology supported precisely in even dimensions.

Comment: ...and, moreover, the $p^{th}$ cup power of a generator of $H^n(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}, \mathbb{Z})$, namely $c_1^n$, is a generator of $H^{np}(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}, \mathbb{Z})$, namely $c_1^{np}$.